# Integrate $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}(x-1/2)^{-3} &\text{if}, 0<y<|x-1/2| \\ 0 &\text{else} \end{cases}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}(x-1/2)^{-3} &\text{if}, 0<y<|x-1/2| \\ 0 &\text{else}  \end{cases}$
>
> I have to integrate it over $E=[0,1]\times[0,1]$

I can integrate the inner integral with respect to $dy$ then $dx$ but how can I do it the other way around (first $dx$ then $dy$); I have problem with the limits

First;

$y<\begin{cases}\frac12-x &\text{if}, x\le\frac12 \\ x-\frac{1}{2} &\text{if}, x >\frac12 \end{cases}$

$\displaystyle\int\int f\ dydx=\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{1/2-x}(1/2-x)^{-3}dydx+\int_{1/2}^{1}\int_0^{x-1/2}(1/2-x)^{-3}dydx=\int_{0}^{1/2}(1/2-x)^{-2}dx-\int_{1/2}^{1}(1/2-x)^{-2}dx=\infty-\infty$

$\displaystyle\int\int f\ dxdy=?$

Comment: Now why would one want to compute the double integral both ways? One way is enough to get the result, no?

Comment: @Did I have to investigate if Fubini is allowed, of course I can integrate $|f|$ and see if it's infinity, the answer is no, but this is another possibility and I can't do it.

Comment: If integrating $|f|$ yields an infinite result, one cannot integrate $f$ on $E$. Sorry but I fail to see a question here.

Comment: @Did you see, at first, I integrated the inner integral w.r.to $dy$ and the limits are from $0$ to $1/2-x$. Now how would it look like, if I would integrate w.r. to $dx$ first, I mean the limits in terms of $y$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is an occasion to recall that rigorous notations help. Here the function $f:E\to\mathbb R$ is defined by
$$
f(x,y)=(x-a)^{-3}\,\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt|x-a|}\,\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt 1},
$$
where $a=\frac12$, hence the integral of $|f|$ (which exists, as an extended nonnegative real number) is
$$
\iint_E|f|=\int_0^1|x-a|^{-3}\int_0^{|x-a|}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx=\int_0^1|x-a|^{-2}\mathrm dx=+\infty.
$$
A consequence is that a formula such as
$$
\iint_Ef(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy
$$
is undefined.